# MySql AVG() and WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, average

I'm struggling on how to write this query and cant quite find an answer to help me with my case.

Consider the following table:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| ID | Value1  | Value2 | Value3 | Date       |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 10      | 23     | 30     | 2015-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 11      | 33     | 40     | 2015-02-01 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 26      | 93     | 20     | 2015-01-01 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 11      | 33     | 50     | 2015-02-01 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve the average value of Value1 where the Date is 2015-01-01

I thought that

```
SELECT AVG(PAM_1) FROM MyTable WHERE DATE = 2015-01-01
```

would work but of course it does not. I'm aware that I probably need to use HAVING but I'm being confused if I must also use GROUP BY and if do I need the AS (something) part.

EDIT

The problem was not related to the query. I was supplying the date trough a variable as such:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT AVG(Value1) FROM MyTable WHERE DATE = $date");
```

Which is not possible to do with prepared statements.

Comment: "but of course it does not" --- it's not obvious why it should not

Comment: You're doing arithmetic: `2015 - 1 - 1 = 2013`, which casts to a  null date value

Comment: use like single quote and double quote for that. example "SELECT AVG(PAM_1) FROM MyTable WHERE DATE = '".  $date . "'"

Comment: It does not because I was using a prepared statement and was inserting the variable holding the date directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically fine.  Your date constant is not.  Dates constants should be enclosed in single quotes:

```
SELECT AVG(PAM_1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATE = '2015-01-01';
```

If the date could have a time component, then the following is the best way to handle this:

```
SELECT AVG(PAM_1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATE >= '2015-01-01' AND DATE < '2015-01-02';
```

Comment: i prefer `WHERE DATE = DATE('2015-01-01')` for the 2nd point, but perhaps that's not as efficient?

Comment: Ugh... Actually for my date I was using a variable in the statement. A prepared statement. So I was dumb of course. The variable must be declared in execute(). Thank you.